# Is it possible to catch the click event for a particular word click from a Text in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Text component in QML which contain seemore along with some text. Ex. This is the details...seemore. Now if only I clicked on seemore I want to perform some operation not any other places of the Text. I tried something with html tags but it not worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not provide an MCVE it is impossible to point out why your code does not work, so I will limit myself to providing the code that implements what you want:

```
Text {
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: "This is the details...<a href=\"http://foo.com\">seemore</a>."
    onLinkActivated: console.log(link + " link activated")
}
```